# Replacing numbers and characters

Tags: excel

In column A, Sheet 1, I have A, B, C, D ( A2:A5), I want to replace these letters with 2,4,6,8, in sheet 2

I have used the following function:

=INDEX($C$2:$C$5,MATCH(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!$D$2:$D$5,0))

But I got an error,how I can solve this issue, Thanks

Comment: "But I got an error" -- Any particular reason you're keeping the error message a secret?

Comment: the error  is #N/A

Comment: This is normally an indication that no match is found. Try the `Match` formula by itself (without the `Index`) first and see if you get the correct result. If I am correct in my assumption you might want to check for leading or trailing spaces in the cell (example `A ` instead of just `A`). Also, are you using Cyrillic characters or any other alphabet which looks like Latin characters? `ChrW(1040)` is *not* equivalent to `ChrW(65)` for a `Match` formula.

Comment: I have removed leading or trailing spaces of all cells. I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I don't know what you have in column C or D but I put:

C2:C5 2,4,6,8
D2:D5 A,B,C,D

I think you have your Index and Match references the wrong way around.

Your match should be Match the letter with the column of letters. Then Index that to the column of numbers.